# React Native Flatlist Not Rerendering Redux

Tags: javascript, react-native, chat, react-native-flatlist, listitem

My FlatList does not update when the props I pass from redux change.  Every time I send a message I increase everyones unread message count in both firebase and in my redux store.  I made sure to include key extractor and extra data, but neither helps.  The only thing that changes the unread message count is a reload of the device.  How do I make sure the flatList updates with MapStateToProps.  I made sure to create a new object by using Object.Assign:

action:

```
export const sendMessage = (
  message,
  currentChannel,
  channelType,
  messageType
) => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(chatMessageLoading());
    const currentUserID = firebaseService.auth().currentUser.uid;
    let createdAt = firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;
    let chatMessage = {
      text: message,
      createdAt: createdAt,
      userId: currentUserID,
      messageType: messageType
    };


    FIREBASE_REF_MESSAGES.child(channelType)
      .child(currentChannel)
      .push(chatMessage, error => {
        if (error) {
          dispatch(chatMessageError(error.message));
        } else {
          dispatch(chatMessageSuccess());
        }
      });

    const UNREAD_MESSAGES = FIREBASE_REF_UNREAD.child(channelType)
      .child(currentChannel).child('users')

    UNREAD_MESSAGES.once("value")
      .then(snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(user => {
          let userKey = user.key;
          // update unread messages count
          if (userKey !== currentUserID) {
            UNREAD_MESSAGES.child(userKey).transaction(function (unreadMessages) {
              if (unreadMessages === null) {
                dispatch(unreadMessageCount(currentChannel, 1))
                return 1;
              } else {
                alert(unreadMessages)
                dispatch(unreadMessageCount(currentChannel, unreadMessages + 1))
                return unreadMessages + 1;
              }
            });
          } else {
            UNREAD_MESSAGES.child(userKey).transaction(function () {
              dispatch(unreadMessageCount(currentChannel, 0))
              return 0;
            });
          }
        }
        )
      })
  };
};

export const getUserPublicChannels = () => {
  return (dispatch, state) => {
    dispatch(loadPublicChannels());
    let currentUserID = firebaseService.auth().currentUser.uid;
    // get all mountains within distance specified
    let mountainsInRange = state().session.mountainsInRange;
    // get the user selected mountain
    let selectedMountain = state().session.selectedMountain;

    // see if the selected mountain is in range to add on additional channels
    let currentMountain;
    mountainsInRange
      ? (currentMountain =
        mountainsInRange.filter(mountain => mountain.id === selectedMountain)
          .length === 1
          ? true
          : false)
      : (currentMountain = false);

    // mountain public channels (don't need to be within distance)
    let currentMountainPublicChannelsRef = FIREBASE_REF_CHANNEL_INFO.child(
      "Public"
    )
      .child(`${selectedMountain}`)
      .child("Public");

    // mountain private channels- only can see if within range
    let currentMountainPrivateChannelsRef = FIREBASE_REF_CHANNEL_INFO.child(
      "Public"
    )
      .child(`${selectedMountain}`)
      .child("Private");

    // get public channels
    return currentMountainPublicChannelsRef
      .orderByChild("key")
      .once("value")
      .then(snapshot => {
        let publicChannelsToDownload = [];

        snapshot.forEach(channelSnapshot => {
          let channelId = channelSnapshot.key;
          let channelInfo = channelSnapshot.val();
          // add the channel ID to the download list

          const UNREAD_MESSAGES = FIREBASE_REF_UNREAD.child("Public")
            .child(channelId).child('users').child(currentUserID)
          UNREAD_MESSAGES.on("value",snapshot => {
              if (snapshot.val() === null) {
                // get number of messages in thread if haven't opened
                dispatch(unreadMessageCount(channelId, 0));
              } else {
                dispatch(unreadMessageCount(channelId, snapshot.val()));
              }
            }
            )
          publicChannelsToDownload.push({ id: channelId, info: channelInfo });
        });

        // flag whether you can check in or not
        if (currentMountain) {
          dispatch(checkInAvailable());
        } else {
          dispatch(checkInNotAvailable());
        }

        // if mountain exists then get private channels/ if in range
        if (currentMountain) {
          currentMountainPrivateChannelsRef
            .orderByChild("key")
            .on("value", snapshot => {
              snapshot.forEach(channelSnapshot => {
                let channelId = channelSnapshot.key;
                let channelInfo = channelSnapshot.val();


                const UNREAD_MESSAGES = FIREBASE_REF_UNREAD.child("Public")
                  .child(channelId).child('users').child(currentUserID)
                UNREAD_MESSAGES.on("value",
                  snapshot => {
                    if (snapshot.val() === null) {
                      // get number of messages in thread if haven't opened
                      dispatch(unreadMessageCount(channelId, 0));
                    } else {
                     dispatch(unreadMessageCount(channelId, snapshot.val()));
                    }
                  }
                  )
                publicChannelsToDownload.push({ id: channelId, info: channelInfo });
              });
            });
        }
        return publicChannelsToDownload;
      })

      .then(data => {
        setTimeout(function () {
          dispatch(loadPublicChannelsSuccess(data));
        }, 150);
      });
  };
};
```

Reducer:

```
case types.UNREAD_MESSAGE_SUCCESS:
        const um = Object.assign(state.unreadMessages, {[action.info]: action.unreadMessages});
    return {
      ...state,
      unreadMessages: um
    };
```

Container- inside I hook up map state to props with the unread messages and pass to my component as props:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
return {
  publicChannels: state.chat.publicChannels,
  unreadMessages: state.chat.unreadMessages,
};
}
```

Component:

```
render() {
    // rendering all public channels
    const renderPublicChannels = ({ item, unreadMessages }) => {
      return (
        <ListItem
          title={item.info.Name}
          titleStyle={styles.title}
          rightTitle={(this.props.unreadMessages || {} )[item.id] > 0 && `${(this.props.unreadMessages || {} )[item.id]}`}
          rightTitleStyle={styles.rightTitle}
          rightSubtitleStyle={styles.rightSubtitle}
          rightSubtitle={(this.props.unreadMessages || {} )[item.id] > 0 && "unread"}
          chevron={true}
          bottomDivider={true}
          id={item.Name}
          containerStyle={styles.listItemStyle}
        />
      );
    };


    return (
        <View style={styles.channelList}>
          <FlatList
            data={this.props.publicChannels}
            renderItem={renderPublicChannels}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
            extraData={[this.props.publicChannels, this.props.unreadMessages]}
            removeClippedSubviews={false}
          />
        </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) will merge everything into the first object provided as an argument, and return the same object. In redux, you need to create a new object reference, otherwise change is not guaranteed to be be picked up. Use this

```
const um = Object.assign({}, state.unreadMessages, {[action.info]: action.unreadMessages});
// or
const um = {...state.unreadMessages, [action.info]: action.unreadMessages }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this still doesn't update the FlatList, so it's an issue outside Object.assign.  No idea what

Comment: It's not possible to tell what's wrong from the code you provided. You will have to do some debugging yourself - start with substituting your Firebase action for something simpler that will just dispatch `types.UNREAD_MESSAGE_SUCCESS` action and see if it works that way. If it does then you know the error was in the original action logic so you can look there. Alternatively, simple console.log in your render will help you determine whether or not your props actually change the right way, and if they do, you'll know the problem is inside your FlatList component

Comment: I think it has something to do with how I am using ref.on inside of getUserPublicChannels which I added to the above code.  Unfortunately I have another issue open with firebase where with >.60 I am unable to console.log() in debug so I am relying on alerts for now which makes it really hard to debug

Comment: I was able to get it working by using on and your above code changes and switching to on.  Stupidly I was using once before.  Marked as correct since it was half the problem

Answer (score 0):

Object.assign() does not return a new object. Due to which in the reducer unreadMessages is pointing to the same object and the component is not getting rerendered.

Use this in your reducer

```
const um = Object.assign({}, state.unreadMessages, {[action.info]: action.unreadMessages});
```

Comment: Unfortunately this still doesn't update the FlatList, so it's an issue outside Object.assign.  No idea what